# ID of d3 selection undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After selecting an element by ID I find the ID to be undefined.

To illustrate this I put together [this example (fiddle link)](https://jsfiddle.net/0h9Lq1hk/)

Set up elements:

```
<pre id='output'></pre>
<input id='my-checkbox' type='checkbox'>
```

The d3 script:

```
d3.select('#my-checkbox')
    .call(function(){
        document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = this.id;
    })
    .on('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = this.id;
    });
```

This fills the pre element with "undefined" which persists even when clicking the box. On the other hand the script below works as I would expect:

```
d3.select('#my-checkbox')
    .on('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = this.id;
    });
```

What is going on here? How can I access the element's ID within d3's `call` function?

Comment: Is your javascript code at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Check out the fiddle I linked to. The JS is after my elements get defined.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the element object as the first argument:

```
d3.select('#my-checkbox').call(function(s){
    document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = s.attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Do you know why this works with `call` when `this.id` does not?

Comment: I do not know exactly why d3 pass the element as an argument in this case. I know is a bit confusing since `on` will pass the element as the context. Probably the context in this case is something else?

Answer (score 1):

From the d3 documentation

> Like function.call, invokes each registered callback for the specified type, passing the callback the specified arguments, with that as the this context. See dispatch.apply for more information.

The function you are looking for is `each`

```
.each(function(){
    document.getElementById('output').outerHTML = this.id;
})
```